# How to return value with RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

Let's consider this situation. We have some class which has one method which returns some value:

```
public class Foo() {
    Observer<File> fileObserver;
    Observable<File> fileObservable;
    Subscription subscription;

    public File getMeThatThing(String id) {
        // implement logic in Observable<File> and return value which was
        // emitted in onNext(File)
    }
}
```

How to return that value which was received in `onNext`? What would be the correct approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need a better understanding of RxJava first, what the Observable -> push model is. This is the solution for reference:

```
public class Foo {
    public static Observable<File> getMeThatThing(final String id) {
        return Observable.defer(() => {
          try {
            return Observable.just(getFile(id));
          } catch (WhateverException e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
          }
        });
    }
}


//somewhere in the app
public void doingThings(){
  ...
  // Synchronous
  Foo.getMeThatThing(5)
   .subscribe(new OnSubscribed<File>(){
     public void onNext(File file){ // your file }
     public void onComplete(){  }
     public void onError(Throwable t){ // error cases }
  });

  // Asynchronous, each observable subscription does the whole operation from scratch
  Foo.getMeThatThing("5")
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .subscribe(new OnSubscribed<File>(){
     public void onNext(File file){ // your file }
     public void onComplete(){  }
     public void onError(Throwable t){ // error cases }
  });

  // Synchronous and Blocking, will run the operation on another thread while the current one is stopped waiting.
  // WARNING, DANGER, NEVER DO IN MAIN/UI THREAD OR YOU MAY FREEZE YOUR APP
  File file = 
  Foo.getMeThatThing("5")
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .toBlocking().first();
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just started experimenting with RxJava. I am in situation where my method needs to return `File` and not `Observable<File>` as many other parts of the app are requesting `File`. Would that be possible? To wait until there is a result and then return it.

Comment: The whole point of RxJava is that, turning pull model (get me this now) into a push model (I'm waiting for this data here). It requires rethinking the way you do your methods. The gains are that the push model is composable, single error handling, and pararellizing operations is trivial.

Comment: Now, unless you start using schedulers for threading and pararellization, your observables will execute the operation synchronously as soon as subscribe hits.

Comment: Thanks. I need to return File and not Observable as my class implements certain interface which I can't change. I guess RxJava is then not suitable in my case.

Comment: There is a way. RxJava has a method called .toBlocking() which transforms it into a BlockingObservable. BO has a method called .first() which returns the first element received, synchronously. You're not gaining anything by using RxJava that way in this context.

I'll add it to the example.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation :) This helps a lot!

Comment: How to pass Observable data inbetween fragments/activities?