# URL.openStream networkOnMainThread using rxAndroid

Tags: java, android

I am using XmlPullParser which parse file from server, of course I am doing it in another thread. I am using rxAndroid to work with threads, but it throws `NetworkOnMainThread` exception. Please help me.

```
public static List<ArticleModel> parseArticles(String get) {

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        URL url = new URL(get);
        **parser.setInput(url.openStream(),null);** // HERE GOES THE EXCEPTION
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("article")) {
                        // create a new instance of employee
                        articleModel =new ArticleModel();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("article")) {
                        // add employee object to list

                        articleModelList.add(articleModel);
                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                        articleModel.setId(text);

                    }  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                       articleModel.setName(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("image_url")) {
                        articleModel.setImage_url(text);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                        articleModel.setUrl(text);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("type")) {
                        articleModel.setType(text);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return articleModelList;
}
```

And this is my RX method:

```
public void getArticles(String get, final boolean needRefresh) throws IOException {

    Observable.just(XmlPullParserHanlder.parseArticles(get))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<ArticleModel>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i("SIZE", "onNext: "+ e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ArticleModel> articleModels) {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I guess you are calling `parseArticles()` from UI thread, that's why you get that exception.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari what's the problem with calling rx method from UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with calling Rx methods from UI thread. The issue is you have do your network operation which is `parseArticles()` in non-UI thread.

You can try this approach -

```
public void getArticles(String get, final boolean needRefresh) throws IOException {

             Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List< ArticleModel >>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super List< ArticleModel >> subscriber) {

                        subscriber.onNext(parseArticles(get));
                        subscriber.onCompleted();

                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<ArticleModel>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i("SIZE", "onNext: "+ e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ArticleModel> articleModels) {

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: how to handle xmlparseexception in call method?

Comment: I guess you are already doing it in parseArticles().

Comment: Why your void return result?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949180/how-to-return-value-with-rxjava

Comment: Your code is working good, Ive deleted return command.Thank you

Comment: Oh yeah ,  right .

Answer (score 0):

You use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`this is fine but this is for the result of `Observable.just(XmlPullParserHanlder.parseArticles(get))`and not for the `XmlPullParserHanlder.parseArticles(get)`method itself. Try something like this

```
Observable.just(get)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
   .map(url -> XmlPullParserHanlder.parseArticles(url))
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(new Observer<List<ArticleModel>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.i("SIZE", "onNext: "+ e.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<ArticleModel> articleModels) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: I can't subscribe this object. Please update your code